# Remove the rows when the values of the all the specific 4 columns are NaN in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

df:

```
ID       Type         Desc         D_N    D_A    C_N     C_A
1        Edu          Education    3      100    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    8       900
1        Eat          Food         4      200    NaN     NaN
1        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         NaN          NaN    NaN    4       700
1        Eat          Food         NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
2        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    1       100
2        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    8       NaN
2        Eat          Food         4      200    NaN     NaN
3        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
3        Bank         NaN          2      300    NaN     NaN
3        Eat          Food         NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

About the df:

whenever `D_N` non-NaN `D_A` should be non-NaN, at the same time `C_N` and `C_A` should be NaN and vice versa.

In the above data, I would like to filter rows where any of the `D_N`, `D_A`, `C_N` and `C_A` are non-NaN

Expected Output:

```
ID       Type         Desc         D_N    D_A    C_N     C_A
1        Edu          Education    3      100    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    8       900
1        Eat          Food         4      200    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         NaN          NaN    NaN    4       700
2        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    1       100
2        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    8       NaN
2        Eat          Food         4      200    NaN     NaN
3        Bank         NaN          2      300    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(df.dropna(subset=["D_N", "D_A", "C_N", "C_A"], how="all"))
```

Prints:

```
    ID  Type       Desc  D_N    D_A  C_N    C_A
0    1   Edu  Education  3.0  100.0  NaN    NaN
1    1  Bank     In_Pay  NaN    NaN  8.0  900.0
2    1   Eat       Food  4.0  200.0  NaN    NaN
4    1  Bank        NaN  NaN    NaN  4.0  700.0
6    2   Edu  Education  NaN    NaN  1.0  100.0
7    2  Bank     In_Pay  NaN    NaN  8.0    NaN
8    2   Eat       Food  4.0  200.0  NaN    NaN
10   3  Bank        NaN  2.0  300.0  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In the same df I would like to filter rows where exactly one of those coulms has non-NaN values.

Comment: @Danish You can do something like `df[df.loc[:, ["D_N", "D_A", "C_N", "C_A"]].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick responses. I tried that unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @Danish Try to replace `.isna()` with `.notna()`